# Realm Swift crashing with uncaught exception when trying to get object

Tags: swift, macos, realm

I am using RealmSwift in my MacOS/OSX application on OSX 10.12.3 and Realm crashes with uncaught exception when I try to get an object from the database.

Here's the code snippet that crashes on the get object func:

```
private var database: Realm!

init(some_var: String) {
  var configuration = Realm.Configuration()
  configuration.fileURL = configuration.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(some_var).realm")
  do {
    debugPrint("Inside init: Current thread \(Thread.current)")
    self.database = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
  } catch {
    debugPrint("realmInit: Can't create realm database.")
  }
}

func getObject<T: Object, K>(with primaryKey: K) -> T? {
  debugPrint("Inside getObject: Current thread \(Thread.current)")
  return self.database.object(ofType: T.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) // THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
}
```

I get a crash with an uncaught exception:

```
"Inside init: Current thread <NSThread: 0x600000075700>{number = 5, name = (null)}"
"Inside getObject: Current thread <NSThread: 0x600000075700>{number = 5, name = (null)}"
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

At first I thought it was a threading issue, but you can see that I init the Realm and getObject on the same thread.

Any help would be appreciated please?

Comment: most probably configuration.fileURL == nil, why you are using the strange forced unwrapping?

Comment: Interesting, I'll try and see if that's the problem and reply back what I find. Not really sure why I force unwrap that tbh, I think I must've just grabbed it off a sample somewhere.

Comment: That didn't turn out to be the issue, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the return type being an ***optional generic***.

After a conversation with one of the contributors to the Realm library on github, it sounded like it could potentially be a RealmSwift bug.

Issue has been raised here https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4951

Workaround is to implement a function that returns a `Bool` if the object exists, and then return a non-optional generic when it does, while create a new object if it doesn't exist.